Graphical relation between kinetic energy and mass
If we plot the graph of kinetic energy and mass through the formula KE = 1/2(mv^2), this would give a straight line but when we use KE = p^2/2m , where p is momentum, and then we plot the graph between KE and m, this would give a rectangular hyperbola curve.
Now, how's it is possible to have two completely different relation between two quantities?
Which one is correct?
What is the explanation for this?

Since $p=m \cdot v$, it is still linear proportional to the mass. So "the straight line" is correct.

Thats's because $p$ is a function of the mass, not just a constant. So when you plot $KE$ as a function of the mass using the momentum $p$, it's like :
\begin{equation}
KE(m)=\frac{p^2(m)}{2m}=\frac{m^2v^2}{2m}=\frac{mv^2}{2}
\end{equation}
You can not ignore the mass dependence of the momentum when you plot your function $KE(m)$.
